# C# How get previous value in the same label in ListView_ItemDataBound?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have to calculate the current value after subtracting the previous value but I do not know how to find the previous value in my `ListView1_ItemDataBound`
I found only for the current value:

```
Label Point = (Label) e.Item.FindControl ("Point") as Label;
```

For example, "point" gives

```
1000
2000
5000
7000
```

And now I have to calculate how many, for example, these 7000 - 5000 will be

```
              <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GroupItemCount="20" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
           <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <td runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="Point" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Point") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                   </td>
                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                </EditItemTemplate>  
                <GroupTemplate>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                        <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
                    </tr>
                </GroupTemplate>  
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                   </InsertItemTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <td runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="Point" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Point") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                   </td>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table runat="server">
                        <tr runat="server">
                            <td runat="server">
                                <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                    <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                  <SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <td runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="Point" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Point") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                   </td>
                </SelectedItemTemplate>
              </asp:ListView>
        </div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PS_TestConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Point] FROM [END]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Like that :
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
            {
                Label Point = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Point") as Label;
                Label Previous = ?? // and here is the problem i can't find it
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(Point.Text);
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(Previous.Text);
                int sum = 0;
                sum = a - b;
                Label1.Text = Sum.ToString();
            }

Comment: Basically, A Program would have `data` => `view` structure. It means we know data before represent data to the label  on view side.   I do not know why a program need to get `data`. from view side.  I think it's more easy if you share your full code.

Comment: I add to first post

Answer (score 0):

I test your code in myself.
Based on program structure, Data must be handled by the control part of business logic.

It means that a program shows the manipulated data to the view part that it is now html page.

I read data from SQL database directly with this sample code as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString;
    SqlConnection cnn;
    connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\.;Initial Catalog=asp-Points;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf";
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    cnn.Open();

    SqlCommand command;
    SqlDataReader dataReader;
    string sql, Output = "";
    sql = "Select [Point] from [dbo].[table]";
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    // This logic to handle subtraction of data from database.
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        int point = Convert.ToInt16(dataReader.GetValue(0));
        if (prev != -1)
        {
            calcedPoint = point - prev;
            Output = Output + calcedPoint.ToString() + "</br>";
        }
        prev = point;
    }
    Response.Write(Output);
    dataReader.Close();
    command.Dispose();
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I received a normal result from SQL
But it does not matter, because I added 2 hidden labels 1 with the current RowID and for assigning a new value from sql in this way
Where RowID = @RowID - 1 and in this way i have 2 labels to calculate.
But thank you for your attention, I appreciate it.